# How to check memory usage of application in sgx enclave

Tags: sgx, enclave

So I have a python script running in sgx enclave using graphene. I need to check values like memory utilization and cpu utilization. How can I check these values of the script running inside enclave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For measuring memory utilization of SGX enclaves you can use the Enclave Memory Measurement Tool (*sgx_emmt*). This will report to you the peak usages of: stack, heap, and reserved memory. It has a big limitation that it only reports the statistics after you destroy the enclave.

On Linux, *sgx_emmt* is provided by *sgx-gdb*. Search for a chapter "Enclave Memory Measurement Tool" in the [Developer Reference](https://download.01.org/intel-sgx/sgx-linux/2.13/docs/Intel_SGX_Developer_Reference_Linux_2.13_Open_Source.pdf) for more details.

You can also check [this blog post](https://kai-chi.github.io/sgx/2020/12/20/how-to-measure-enclave-memory-consumption.html) to see how to conveniently use the tool.

For CPU utilization you can take a look at Intel VTune. It has an option [sgx-hotspots](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/command-line-interface/running-command-line-analysis/running-sgx-hotspots-analysis-from-the-command-line.html), which allows to collect statistics from the enclave programs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use global variable `extern size_t g_peak_heap_used;` inside enclave part.